# mongodb number vs _id index for performance?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

suppose I have hobbies collection and 100 hobbies in it. my users has some hobbies and I keep _id values of those hobbies in their **hobbies:[]** array field.

I will create indices on hobbies field of the users. However, I am not sure if I should use _id values of hobbies. Should I give them numbers starting from 0 and use it instead of default _id ?

like {id:0,"football"} , {id:1,"basketball"} , {id:2,"jogging"} .... {id:100,"chess"}

user:{
hobbies:[0,1]
.
.
..
}

or should I keep them as it is

user:{
hobbies:["61464259f1519b04782dc11e","61464259f1519b04782dc11a"]
.
.
..
}

Comment: I [Googled the title of your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+number+vs+_id+index+for+performance), and the answer appears to be "Have the correct number and type of indices."

Answer (score 0):

An integer requires 8 bytes for storage, an object ID requires 12.

In terms of performance, the difference will be negligible.

In terms of storage space, the hobbies collection will be 400 bytes different.
If you have 1000 users with an average of 5 hobbies, the storage space of the users collection will differ by ~2MB, which is also negligible on modern systems.

As noted in the comments, performance will be impacted by indexing far more than whether the field is object ID or integer.